# Detect svg coordinates being hovered over

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an SVG element

```
<svg id='win-frame' style='height: 500px; width: 500px;'>
</svg>
```

Say that the mouse is hovering over the svg element. Is there a way to display the coordinates of the point being hovered over by the mouse, either in a tooltip, or a div below the svg? This would preferably use javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add text field to show coordinates:

```
<input type="text" id="coords" readonly></input>
```

Then handle the `mousemove` and `mouseout` events to fill the `coords` input with coordinates:

```js
/* create an svg drawing */
var draw = SVG('win-frame');

/* draw rectangle */
var rect = draw.rect(200, 200).fill('#f09')
var coordsDiv = document.getElementById('coords');
rect.mousemove(function(evt) {
  coordsDiv.value = evt.clientX + ' ' + evt.clientY;
}).mouseout(function() {
  coordsDiv.value = '';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.0.5/svg.js"></script>
<div id="win-frame"></div>
<input type="text" id="coords" readonly />
```

### EDIT: Pure javascript solution

HTML part:

```
<svg id='win-frame' style='height: 200px; width: 200px;' >
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
</svg>
<input type="text" id="coords" readonly />
```

And javascript part:

```
var coordsDiv = document.getElementById('coords');
var el1 = document.getElementById('win-frame');
el1.onmousemove = function(evt) {
     coordsDiv.value = evt.clientX + ' ' + evt.clientY;
}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fh68sb5/2/

Comment: Ivan i did not ask for svg.js. i said javascript, which means pure javascript, not whatever library you decide to use

Comment: @Leshy: See my edit. This version use `javascript` only.